# C# 4.0, detect if a method is missing

Tags: c#, dynamic, codedom

I have a situation where i want to add LinePragmas to CodeDom objects. But some code dom objects have the LinePragma property and some don't.

So I'm wondering if it's possible to use the dynamic keyword to detect if the property exists on the object (without throwing an exception) and if it does then add the pragma. Here is my current method:

```
public static T SetSource<T>(this T codeObject, INode sourceNode)
    where T : CodeObject
{
    codeObject.UserData["Node"] = sourceNode.Source;
    dynamic dynamicCodeObject = codeObject;

    // How can I not throw an exception here?
    if (dynamicCodeObject.LinePragma != null)
    {
        dynamicCodeObject.LinePragma = new CodeLinePragma(
        sourceNode.Source.Path.AbsoluteUri,
        sourceNode.Source.StartLine);
    }

    return codeObject;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The solution I went with was to add an extension method called Exists(). I wrote a blog post about it here:
[Member Exists Dynamic C# 4.0](http://justinmchase.com/2009/07/02/member-exists-e28093-dynamic-c-40/)

The jist was to create an extension method that returns an object that implements DynamicObject's TryGetMember. It uses reflection to then return true or false. Which allows you to write code like this:

```
object instance = new { Foo = "Hello World!" };
if (instance.Reflection().Exists().Foo)
{
    string value = instance.Reflection().Call().Foo;
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can detect if an object has a property without having to use the dynamic features of C# 4.0 - instead using the reflection features that have been around for a while (I know at least .NET 2.0, not sure about < 2.0)

```
PropertyInfo info = codeObject.getType().GetProperty(
    "LinePragma", 
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance
)
```

If it the object does not have the property, then GetProperty() will return null.  You can do similar for fields ( GetField() ) and methods ( GetMethod() ).

Not only that, but once you have the PropertyInfo, you can use it directly to do your set:

```
info.SetValue(codeObject, new CodeLinePragma(), null);
```

If you're not sure whether the property has a set method, you could take the even safer route:

```
MethodInfo method = info.GetSetMethod();
if(method != null)
    method.Invoke(codeObject, new object[]{ new CodeLinePragma() });
```

This also gives you the added benefit of being a little more performant over the lookup overhead of the dynamic call (can't find a reference for that statement, so I'll just float it out there).

I suppose that doesn't answer your question directly, but rather is an alternative solution to accomplish the same goal.  I haven't actually used #4.0 features yet (even though I'm a huge fan of the dynamic typing available in Ruby).  It certainly not as clean/readable as the dynamic solution, but if you don't want to throw an exception it may be the way to go.

EDIT: as @arbiter points out, "This is valid only for native .net dynamic objects. This will not work for example for IDispatch."

Comment: This is valid only for native .net dynamic objects. This will not work for example for IDispatch.

Comment: @arbiter ahh, good point.  Clearly demonstrating my lack of experience in actually using .NET 4.0. +1

Comment: @zvolkov I don't understand why your answer suggests this one wont work - can you elaborate?

Comment: This was what I ended up doing too. I was just hoping there would be a more clever and elegant way to do this with the dynamic keyword. Or at least that calling a non-existent property wouldn't throw an exception :(

Comment: The question wasn't that this works for any dynamic object but especially for classes in the CodeDOM namespace. The API is somewhat messy: There are no indicators which classes have LinePragma and which don't. So you're stuck with plenty of type checks or do something with reflection or indeed use dynamic.

Comment: This won't work if the target class implements IDynamicObject or subclasses DynamicObject. See my answer below for details.

Comment: I went with a reflection based approach in the end. Here is my solution:
http://justnbusiness.com/post/2009/07/02/Member-Exists-e28093-Dynamic-C-40.aspx

Basically has a fluent style API with a dynamic wrapper for seeing if unknown members exist first.

Answer (score 5):

I just spent almost an hour searching for ways to get some kind of ruby-esque "RespondTo" Method on dynamic. There certainly isn't an easy answer, but I haven't given up yet.

The point made on reflection should be the thing to try.

With dynamic, the only thing I get so far is an extension method that treats your object as dynamic. If it works, it works, if not it silently fails...

```
public static void Dynamight<T>(this T target, Action<dynamic> action)
{
  dynamic d = target;
  try
  {
    action(d);
  }
  catch (RuntimeBinderException)
  {
    //That was that, didn't work out
  }
}
```

Then you can do...

```
string h = "Hello";
h.Dynamight(d => Console.WriteLine(d.Length)); //Prints out 5
h.Dynamight(d => d.Foo()); //Nothing happens
```

**Update:**

Since I am getting downvotes and what-have-you let me be more concise than the subtle naming of the extension method: It is **dynamite** (Geddit?)! Gobbling exceptions and doing nothing is **bad**. This is no production code, but a version 1 of a spike of a proof of concept.  I keep forgetting that you can't be subtle on a multi-thousands forum like stackoverflow. Mea culpa.

Comment: +1 Pretty cool stuff.  But when does it start getting too clever?

Comment: I'm not sure about the silent failure there - sounds like setting up a scenario where a bug will disappear into a black hole of obscurity.  In Ruby you still get a run time error if there is no method - *unless* the class also defines the method_missing method.  And even then you have the choice to handle it as you see fit and still drop an "undefined method" error if you so choose.

Comment: The extension method only swallows a RuntimeBinderException, which is the desired behavior in this scenario. All other exceptions would pass up the call stack. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: I thought theught the "might" misspelling was a bit of a joke since the method "might" not exist?

Answer (score 3):

18 months later ... it seems like what you really wanted is there now that it's released. It's the **TryGetMember**, **TryGetValue**, etc... actually, probably **[TrySetMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trysetmember.aspx)**, specifically.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject_members.aspx

Comment: TryGetMember only exists on objects that inherit from DynamicObject though... casting it to (dynamic) isn't quite the same as casting it to (DynamicObject). When you cast it to dynamic and try to call members on it the it will call TryGetValue on the dynamic wrapper and throw an exception if it fails.

I suppose it might possible to cast it like "(DynamicObject)(dynamic)obj" ?

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to chime in and say static typing would avoid this problem.

This is a candidate for an abstract method with overriding.

Comment: Well the problem here is that I'm trying to access a property on CodeDom objects. If you're not familiar there are probably 50 of them and maybe half or so with the LinePragma property. Unfortunately, that property is not found on any particular shared base type or interface. So with strong typing you have to do a try and fail cast of a whole bunch of objects in order to find the right one. Very tedious.

Answer (score -1):

Think about it: since the target class can provide its own implementation for the member lookup and invocation for non-existing members (by implementing IDynamicObject or subclassing DynamicObject) the only way to verify if a member exists **is to invoke it and see whether the object handles it or throws an exception**.

Once again, handling of non-existing members is DYNAMIC!

--EDIT--

If you control object creation, you could subclass the class and implement IDynamicObject to signal your other class that method does not exist.

It's unfair to downvote the answer if it points out the truth -- i.e. **that there's no and cannot be** a *reliable* way to check member existence in dynamic dispatch environment **other than invoking the member**.

Comment: It's not my type, I cannot add interfaces too it. :(

Comment: Also, invoking a non-existent member throws an exception. I need more of a TryInvoke type of thing.

Comment: This is all nice, but the question is about CodeDom objects, that are not dynamic. And he was just wondering if C#4 could help to discover the property. Also there's no need for UPPER CASING A WHOLE SENTENCE JUST TO TRY TO MAKE A POINT.

Comment: The title was "C# 4.0, detect if a method is missing" -- which is exactly what I addressed. Valid point re: caps though, fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace System.Dynamic
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Provides a base class for specifying dynamic behavior at run time. This class
    //     must be inherited from; you cannot instantiate it directly.
    public class DynamicObject : IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Enables derived types to initialize a new instance of the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
        //     type.
        protected DynamicObject();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns the enumeration of all dynamic member names.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A sequence that contains dynamic member names.
        public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides a System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject that dispatches to the dynamic virtual
        //     methods. The object can be encapsulated inside another System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject
        //     to provide custom behavior for individual actions. This method supports the Dynamic
        //     Language Runtime infrastructure for language implementers and it is not intended
        //     to be used directly from your code.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   parameter:
        //     The expression that represents System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject to dispatch to
        //     the dynamic virtual methods.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     An object of the System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject type.
        public virtual DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(Expression parameter);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides implementation for binary operations. Classes derived from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
        //     class can override this method to specify dynamic behavior for operations such
        //     as addition and multiplication.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   binder:
        //     Provides information about the binary operation. The binder.Operation property
        //     returns an System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType object. For example, for the
        //     sum = first + second statement, where first and second are derived from the DynamicObject
        //     class, binder.Operation returns ExpressionType.Add.
        //
        //   arg:
        //     The right operand for the binary operation. For example, for the sum = first
        //     + second statement, where first and second are derived from the DynamicObject
        //     class, arg is equal to second.
        //
        //   result:
        //     The result of the binary operation.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the operation is successful; otherwise, false. If this method returns
        //     false, the run-time binder of the language determines the behavior. (In most
        //     cases, a language-specific run-time exception is thrown.)
        public virtual bool TryBinaryOperation(BinaryOperationBinder binder, object arg, out object result);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides implementation for type conversion operations. Classes derived from
        //     the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject class can override this method to specify dynamic
        //     behavior for operations that convert an object from one type to another.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   binder:
        //     Provides information about the conversion operation. The binder.Type property
        //     provides the type to which the object must be converted. For example, for the
        //     statement (String)sampleObject in C# (CType(sampleObject, Type) in Visual Basic),
        //     where sampleObject is an instance of the class derived from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
        //     class, binder.Type returns the System.String type. The binder.Explicit property
        //     provides information about the kind of conversion that occurs. It returns true
        //     for explicit conversion and false for implicit conversion.
        //
        //   result:
        //     The result of the type conversion operation.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the operation is successful; otherwise, false. If this method returns
        //     false, the run-time binder of the language determines the behavior. (In most
        //     cases, a language-specific run-time exception is thrown.)
        public virtual bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides the implementation for operations that initialize a new instance of
        //     a dynamic object. This method is not intended for use in C# or Visual Basic.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   binder:
        //     Provides information about the initialization operation.
        //
        //   args:
        //     The arguments that are passed to the object during initialization. For example,
        //     for the new SampleType(100) operation, where SampleType is the type derived from
        //     the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject class, args[0] is equal to 100.
        //
        //   result:
        //     The result of the initialization.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the operation is successful; otherwise, false. If this method returns
        //     false, the run-time binder of the language determines the behavior. (In most
        //     cases, a language-specific run-time exception is thrown.)
        public virtual bool TryCreateInstance(CreateInstanceBinder binder, object[] args, out object result);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides the implementation for operations that delete an object by index. This
        //     method is not intended for use in C# or Visual Basic.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   binder:
        //     Provides information about the deletion.
        //
        //   indexes:
        //     The indexes to be deleted.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the operation is successful; otherwise, false. If this method returns
        //     false, the run-time binder of the language determines the behavior. (In most
        //     cases, a language-specific run-time exception is thrown.)
        public virtual bool TryDeleteIndex(DeleteIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides the implementation for operations that delete an object member. This
        //     method is not intended for use in C# or Visual Basic.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   binder:
        //     Provides information about the deletion.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the operation is successful; otherwise, false. If this method returns
        //     false, the run-time binder of the language determines the behavior. (In most
        //     cases, a language-specific run-time exception is thrown.)
        public virtual bool TryDeleteMember(DeleteMemberBinder binder);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides the implementation for operations that get a value by index. Classes
        //     derived from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject class can override this method
        //     to specify dynamic behavior for indexing operations.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   binder:
        //     Provides information about the operation.
        //
        //   indexes:
        //     The indexes that are used in the operation. For example, for the sampleObject[3]
        //     operation in C# (sampleObject(3) in Visual Basic), where sampleObject is derived
        //     from the DynamicObject class, indexes[0] is equal to 3.
        //
        //   result:
        //     The result of the index operation.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the operation is successful; otherwise, false. If this method returns
        //     false, the run-time binder of the language determines the behavior. (In most
        //     cases, a run-time exception is thrown.)
        public virtual bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides the implementation for operations that get member values. Classes derived
        //     from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject class can override this method to specify
        //     dynamic behavior for operations such as getting a value for a property.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   binder:
        //     Provides information about the object that called the dynamic operation. The
        //     binder.Name property provides the name of the member on which the dynamic operation
        //     is performed. For example, for the Console.WriteLine(sampleObject.SampleProperty)
        //     statement, where sampleObject is an instance of the class derived from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
        //     class, binder.Name returns "SampleProperty". The binder.IgnoreCase property specifies
        //     whether the member name is case-sensitive.
        //
        //   result:
        //     The result of the get operation. For example, if the method is called for a property,
        //     you can assign the property value to result.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the operation is successful; otherwise, false. If this method returns
        //     false, the run-time binder of the language determines the behavior. (In most
        //     cases, a run-time exception is thrown.)
        public virtual bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides the implementation for operations that invoke an object. Classes derived
        //     from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject class can override this method to specify
        //     dynamic behavior for operations such as invoking an object or a delegate.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   binder:
        //     Provides information about the invoke operation.
        //
        //   args:
        //     The arguments that are passed to the object during the invoke operation. For
        //     example, for the sampleObject(100) operation, where sampleObject is derived from
        //     the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject class, args[0] is equal to 100.
        //
        //   result:
        //     The result of the object invocation.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the operation is successful; otherwise, false. If this method returns
        //     false, the run-time binder of the language determines the behavior. (In most
        //     cases, a language-specific run-time exception is thrown.
        public virtual bool TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, object[] args, out object result);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides the implementation for operations that invoke a member. Classes derived
        //     from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject class can override this method to specify
        //     dynamic behavior for operations such as calling a method.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   binder:
        //     Provides information about the dynamic operation. The binder.Name property provides
        //     the name of the member on which the dynamic operation is performed. For example,
        //     for the statement sampleObject.SampleMethod(100), where sampleObject is an instance
        //     of the class derived from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject class, binder.Name
        //     returns "SampleMethod". The binder.IgnoreCase property specifies whether the
        //     member name is case-sensitive.
        //
        //   args:
        //     The arguments that are passed to the object member during the invoke operation.
        //     For example, for the statement sampleObject.SampleMethod(100), where sampleObject
        //     is derived from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject class, args[0] is equal to 100.
        //
        //   result:
        //     The result of the member invocation.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the operation is successful; otherwise, false. If this method returns
        //     false, the run-time binder of the language determines the behavior. (In most
        //     cases, a language-specific run-time exception is thrown.)
        public virtual bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides the implementation for operations that set a value by index. Classes
        //     derived from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject class can override this method
        //     to specify dynamic behavior for operations that access objects by a specified
        //     index.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   binder:
        //     Provides information about the operation.
        //
        //   indexes:
        //     The indexes that are used in the operation. For example, for the sampleObject[3]
        //     = 10 operation in C# (sampleObject(3) = 10 in Visual Basic), where sampleObject
        //     is derived from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject class, indexes[0] is equal to
        //     3.
        //
        //   value:
        //     The value to set to the object that has the specified index. For example, for
        //     the sampleObject[3] = 10 operation in C# (sampleObject(3) = 10 in Visual Basic),
        //     where sampleObject is derived from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject class, value
        //     is equal to 10.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the operation is successful; otherwise, false. If this method returns
        //     false, the run-time binder of the language determines the behavior. (In most
        //     cases, a language-specific run-time exception is thrown.
        public virtual bool TrySetIndex(SetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, object value);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides the implementation for operations that set member values. Classes derived
        //     from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject class can override this method to specify
        //     dynamic behavior for operations such as setting a value for a property.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   binder:
        //     Provides information about the object that called the dynamic operation. The
        //     binder.Name property provides the name of the member to which the value is being
        //     assigned. For example, for the statement sampleObject.SampleProperty = "Test",
        //     where sampleObject is an instance of the class derived from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
        //     class, binder.Name returns "SampleProperty". The binder.IgnoreCase property specifies
        //     whether the member name is case-sensitive.
        //
        //   value:
        //     The value to set to the member. For example, for sampleObject.SampleProperty
        //     = "Test", where sampleObject is an instance of the class derived from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
        //     class, the value is "Test".
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the operation is successful; otherwise, false. If this method returns
        //     false, the run-time binder of the language determines the behavior. (In most
        //     cases, a language-specific run-time exception is thrown.)
        public virtual bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Provides implementation for unary operations. Classes derived from the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
        //     class can override this method to specify dynamic behavior for operations such
        //     as negation, increment, or decrement.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   binder:
        //     Provides information about the unary operation. The binder.Operation property
        //     returns an System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType object. For example, for the
        //     negativeNumber = -number statement, where number is derived from the DynamicObject
        //     class, binder.Operation returns "Negate".
        //
        //   result:
        //     The result of the unary operation.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the operation is successful; otherwise, false. If this method returns
        //     false, the run-time binder of the language determines the behavior. (In most
        //     cases, a language-specific run-time exception is thrown.)
        public virtual bool TryUnaryOperation(UnaryOperationBinder binder, out object result);
    }`enter code here`
}
```